# Printing records with condition Crystal reports

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, crystal-reports

I am using stored procedure in mssql as backend, vb.net as frontend (just info).

There are a lot of records in the database and I am printing in crystal reports.
Now I want to filter the records from crystal report and not by adding a new parameter to procedure or changing database structure or else.

For now,Say there are columns : Name , Amount.

I want to put filter in amount like only display records whose amount above 100 or something. So other records with less than 100 should not be displayed.

This filter will be passed by the user so it'll be random.

I can't find a proper answer on internet. Might be a duplicate question, if so please post the link of the question if it is duplicated.!

Thanx anyways...!

Comment: You can use the Record Selection Formula

Comment: Yeah I seen that but that link was not answered properly...
Now I search for Record Selection Formula and say you if it helped me... @AbdulRasheed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the idea is to:

1. Create the **parameter** (user choose what will be the input/value) - [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_parameters.htm)
2. Set **filters**, what values should be displayed in regards to parameter - [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/crystal_reports/crystal_reports_filters.htm)

On right side there is a `DataExplorer` window, where You need to add a Parameter (define his name, what question will be shown to user and what type the param will be / what values can be set inside).

Once done, You can jump to `Data` tab of a report, click `Interactive Filter` and specify which **column** must fit what **condition** with what value = **Parameter** (that one user will enter in Report).

Example: I will create **AmountParam**, with message *"What should be the minimum amount?"*. Type will be set to **Integer**. Going to `Report`->`Data`->`Interactive Filter`, choose **Amount** as a Column, **AmountParam** as a Parameter and set condition Greater then (>).

Comment: wait a min, where is all these things??
Which crystal report is this??? I am using crystal reports from VS and can't find any single thing described in your answer...

Comment: @bonny Check the links (end of line 1. & 2.)

Comment: Yeah I checked but all seems different...
However I did it in other way.!!
Thank you for the help.. :) @Tatranskymedved